# Which vectors are obtainable by my function?

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, vectors

Imagine a disc with $N$ radially displaceable masses $m_g$.

A total imbalance with respect to the center of the disc can be calculated as follows (using the respective radiuses $r_1,...,r_N$):

$$\vec{U}_s(r_1,...,r_N) = m_g \cdot \sum_{k=1}^N r_k \cdot e^{i \cdot 2\pi \cdot\frac{k - 1}{N}}$$

The radiuses are constrained by 
$$r_k \leq r_{max} \land \left(r_k \geq r_{min} \lor r_k = 0 \right)$$

Now the question is:

How can I determine, which $\vec{U}_s$ can be obtained by all combinations of $r_1,...,r_N$?

EDIT:

A brute-force approach 
(i.e. all combinations of the values ${0, 0.0065, 0.007125, 0.00775, 0.008375, 0.009}$)

for N=5 and some arbitrary values for $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$ shows the following distribution:

[Distribution of my points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVTdK.jpg)

**Answer:**

This is how it looks like, when it's working for N=7 (implemented with Mathatica)

http ://i.stack.imgur.com/krqf0.gif

**RESULT**

I managed to visualize them :)

[Visualization of the Minkovski Sums (N=7) (done with Mathematica)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdt3w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a Minkowski sum of $M\le N$ line segments with different orientations. (Actually, the fact that they have equal length, are aligned with the origin and at reguar angles does not really matter.)

The sum of two such segments is a parallelogram. The sum of three is an hexagon and so on. Depending on the $k$ for wich $r_k>0$, the polygons can be regular/centered or not.

Below a case with $N=7,M=4$.

[image]

You can compute the polygon as the convex hull of the vector sums of all segment endpoints (there are $2^M$ of them).

The points such that $r_k=0$ have no impact (except that if you compute the centroid, they modify the global scale).

Comment: Not sure if i understand your answer. I just added a ListPlot of a brute force approach to my question...

Comment: @dpf: that's exactly it, you have the whole collection of segments, parallelograms, hexagons, octagons and a decagon in the middle.

Comment: :The Minkowski Sum is a good keyword, thanks.

Comment: The cases of one or more $r_k=0$ is of great interest for me, just because of the creation of areas with greater distance to the center - but there are regions between the new areas, which cannot be reached. I want to know the exact shape of the reachable area...

Comment: Example for N=6: [link](https://imgur.com/Z7Extbl)

Comment: @dpf: it's all in my answer, take the convex hulls. If really needed, you can construct the union of the polygons, but this isn't a trivial task.

Comment: you're right. thank you very much! can you recommend a way to visualize all possible convex hulls in one diagram? I don't need a "true" union of them. they can also be plotted on top of each other.

Comment: Do you have a convex hull algorithm handy ? (If not, consider https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain). It might be that there is a rule to immediately tell the vertices of the convex hull, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Just managed to visualize them in Mathematica (see my edit above)